# Reducing page margin of Springer LNCS format

Tags: margins

I am using Springer LNCS format to author a paper. However, the page margin seems to be too wide. How can it be reduced to a decent value? Here is the [CLS style file](ftp://ftp.springer.de/pub/tex/latex/llncs/latex2e/instruct/authors/typeinst.zip). Because of post size limit, I could not post the CLS file itself. Instead, it has been hyperlinked.

Comment: Honestly, since this is for a paper submission to LNCS, you should not bother with any layout properties. Regardless, you can add `\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{margin=2cm}` to your preamble to obtain a 2cm margin on all four sides of the page.

Comment: If it used for a conference submission and they ask for that format (and often with a page limit) you should not change the layout.

Comment: the text block size is designed to fit the paper Springer use for the books, not to look reasonable on a4 paper in proof form. If you change the format it's unlikely to work as an LNCS submission.

Comment: Nope, the conference which I am going to submit it it has a restriction of 14 pages in 11 pt font and 'reasonable' margins. I started with LNCS since this is by far one of the most standard one.

Answer (score 10):

That `llncs` is standard is not true, in my opinion. However, nothing prevents you from using `geometry` with it. Adjust to your needs the parameters I set. Of course, submitting such a document to Springer will cause rejection.

```
\documentclass{llncs}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
  a4paper,         % or letterpaper
  textwidth=15cm,  % llncs has 12.2cm
  textheight=24cm, % llncs has 19.3cm
  heightrounded,   % integer number of lines
  hratio=1:1,      % horizontally centered
  vratio=2:3,      % not vertically centered
}

\usepackage{lipsum} % just for the example

\begin{document}
\frontmatter                                    
\pagestyle{headings}                    

\mainmatter                                 

\title{my title}
\titlerunning{my title}

\author{author1 name\inst{1} and  author2 name\inst{1,2}}
\authorrunning{author1 name}

\authorrunning{Short author list}% Part of LEFT running header
\titlerunning{Short title}% Part of RIGHT running header

\institute{University 1 \\
\email{email1@gmail.com}
\and
University 2 \\
\email{email2@gmail.com}
}

\maketitle            

\begin{abstract}
\lipsum*[2]
\end{abstract}

\section{Introduction}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: One thing with LNCS is that the final paper in the paper repository seems not using the standard margin provided by them. See the margin in a published paper [link](http://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007%2F978-3-642-30220-6_36.pdf)

Comment: @chandresh That's not surprising: Springer provides a generic class for getting documents respecting their markup, so the editors of a particular series or journal can easily adapt the document to the particular standard. That's why it's better not to tweak the default format, if the paper is to be submitted to Springer.